# Power analysis for relative risk equivalent to power analysis for difference between two proportions?

Tags: r, sample-size, statistical-power, relative-risk, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I need to make a power analysis calculation to estimate the minimum sample size for a relative risk statistic (ratio of two proportions) for unmatched data - two independent samples.

Can I use the power calculations in the R `pwr` package for testing the difference between two proportions? Or will this return inaccurate sample size estimates?

EDIT: I see there's a `power.cmh.test` option in the `samplesizeCMH` package that allows you to find power and sample size for Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel tests. Can I apply this to any relative risk statistic, even if it's not a case-control study?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relative risk, $RR$, is simply $RR = \pi_1/\pi_2$ for group probabilities $\pi_i$.  This means that $\pi_1 = RR \pi_2$.

Thus, a power analysis to detect a relative risk of $RR$ is equivalent to a power analysis to detect a risk difference between $\pi_1$ and $RR \pi_2$. See chapter 3 in *Biostatistical Methods 2e* by John Lachin for more.

Comment: Thanks Demetri!